# diff each individual line in first file against all lines in second file?

Tags: command-line, bash, vim, script, diff

I have 2 TCL representations of a project that get generated by 2 different versions of the same tool, let's call them `v1.tcl` and `v2.tcl`

These logs are normally logically identical for all intents and purposes, with the exception of the order of the lines. Every line in `v1.tcl` will be found **somewhere** exactly once in `v2.tcl` when versions 1 and 2 of my project are identical.

I'd like to be able to identify whether someone has made a change in `v2.tcl` that needs to be backported to `v1.tcl` (or vice-versa) ... in other words I'd like to only see the lines in which don't match. For example:

1. `v1.tcl`:

   ```
   foo1
   bar1
   hello1
   world1
   ```
2. `v2.tcl`:

   ```
   hello1
   bar1
   foo2
   world1
   goodbye2
   ```
3. "diff" return value:

   ```
   file1:1 foo1
   file2:3 foo2
   file2:5 goodbye2
   ```

Should I just write my own little script? Is there a tool that already does this?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I tired this, and since it's code, I sometimes get errors about `grep: Trailing backslash`. I'll check the man pages to see if I can get it to treat those as text...

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT just running `grep -vf v2.tcl v1.tcl` errors with "trailing backslash", even if I redirect it somewhere like above.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT If the input files have lines ending in backslashes, grep gives the trailing backslash errors. I used grep's `-F` to fix those, and added your much shorter comment/answer to the end of mine. FYI I didn't use all awk solution, but did add bash/cut/grep to show the filename & lines

Comment: @Xen2050 Very nice solution, good explanation on all that too. I didn't have any Linux to ssh into to test myself from Linux so did the grep I commented on via Windows GNU packages or whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the lines are identical, and you only want to know *if* there's extra lines in one file or another, you could use sort & diff (and Process Substitution here):

```
$ diff -B <(sort v1.tcl) <(sort v2.tcl)
2c2,3
< foo1
---
> foo2
> goodbye2
```

With diff's `-B` to ignore blank lines. You could then use `grep -n [pattern] file` to find which line the pattern is at (maybe with one or a combination of `grep`, `cut`, `sed`, `awk`), if that matters.

Here's a more complete answer, showing the file and line number containing matches. Doesn't use sed or awk, just bash, cut, grep... here's it all (essentially) in one line:

```
diff -B <(sort v1.tcl) <(sort v2.tcl) | while read -r line; do if \
echo "$line" | grep -q "^<"; then grep -F -n -H \
"$(echo "$line"|cut -c3-)" v1.tcl ; elif echo "$line" | grep -q \
"^>"; then grep -F -n -H "$(echo "$line"|cut -c3-)" v2.tcl ; fi done
```

Or split into multiple lines:

```
diff -B <(sort v1.tcl) <(sort v2.tcl) | while read -r line
do
  if echo "$line" | grep -q "^<"
    then grep -F -n -H "$(echo "$line"|cut -c3-)" v1.tcl
  elif echo "$line" | grep -q "^>"
    then grep -F -n -H  "$(echo "$line"|cut -c3-)" v2.tcl
  fi
done
```

And depending on your input files (especially if you have lines with trailing backslashes), I'm using these options for read & grep:

- `read -r`   do not allow backslashes to escape any characters
- `grep -F` Interpret  PATTERN  as  a  list of fixed strings (instead of regular expressions), separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched

---

Also, using [Pimp Juice IT's](https://superuser.com/users/510662/pimp-juice-it) comments, if there's trailing backslashes to lines in the input files grep gives the "file:line Trailing backslash" error. Using the `-F` option for grep to clear the trailing backslash error results in a much smaller grep-only solution:

```
grep -FvHn -f v2.tcl v1.tcl ;grep -FvHn -f v1.tcl v2.tcl
```

grep's options used:

- `-f` Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.
- `-F` Interpret  PATTERN  as  a  list of fixed strings (instead of regular expressions), separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched
- `-v` Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
- `-H` Print  the  file name for each match
- `-n` Prefix each line of output with the 1-based line number within its input file.

Comment: Welcome :) The trailing backslashes was causing problems with my first draft (no `-F` & I think `-r``) answer too, though the sample text worked ok, and extra blank lines were causing weird problems also. But now everything *seems* fine